# Create a combination of unique column names from two dataset without looping

Tags: r, data.table

I have two vectors:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(11,12,13)
```

I want to create a combination of column names (3*3 = 9) such that they use values from both:

```
paper1grid11 
paper1grid12
paper1grid13
paper2grid11
paper2grid12
paper2grid13
paper3grid11
paper3grid12
paper3grid13
```

I have tried using the paste0 command but that doesn't do a combination. Instead it just creates 3 column names.

```
paste0("paper", a,"grid", b)
```

I don't want to use a for loop

Comment: `apply(expand.grid("paper", a, "grid", b), 1, paste, collapse="")`

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! What If I have to add these values as column names with another datset (x) using cbind. How should I be doing it? The values for these new columns can be zero

Comment: Better post it as a another question and accept the answer if it solves the problem for the question you have posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `expand.grid`.

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(11,12,13)
do.call(paste0, expand.grid("paper", a, "grid", b))
```

Comment: Thanks jkd! If I have to add these values as column names  with another datset (x) using cbind. How should I be doing it? The values for these new values can be zero.

Comment: No need for `cbind`, just add the column to the new dataframe: `df$mycolumn <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid("paper", a, "grid", b))`

Comment: But I don't want to add them as just a column but instead create 9 new columns in the other dataset.

Comment: This is probably to complex to be solved in comments, maybe you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `outer`, i.e

```
outer(a, b, function(x, y) paste0('paper', x, 'grid', y))
#     [,1]           [,2]           [,3]          
#[1,] "paper1grid11" "paper1grid12" "paper1grid13"
#[2,] "paper2grid11" "paper2grid12" "paper2grid13"
#[3,] "paper3grid11" "paper3grid12" "paper3grid13"
```

or wrap it around `c` to get the answer as a vector, i.e.

```
c(outer(a, b, function(x, y) paste0('paper', x, 'grid', y)))
#[1] "paper1grid11" "paper2grid11" "paper3grid11" "paper1grid12" "paper2grid12" "paper3grid12" "paper1grid13" "paper2grid13" "paper3grid13"
```

Comment: c(outer(a, b, function(x, y) paste0('paper', x, 'grid', y))), this is better output no need for a matrix I think

Comment: we added it the same time

Comment: matrix(outer(a, b, function(x, y) paste0('paper', x, 'grid', y)))

Answer (score 3):

This post is tagged with `data.table` so here is a `data.table` solution:

```
CJ(a, b)[, paste0("paper", a, "grid", b)]

# [1] "paper1grid11" "paper2grid11" "paper3grid11" "paper1grid12" "paper2grid12"
# [6] "paper3grid12" "paper1grid13" "paper2grid13" "paper3grid13
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(expand.grid("paper", a, "grid", b), 1, paste, collapse="")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use crossing()

```
library(tidyverse)

crossing("paper",a,"grid",b)%>%unite(`"paper"`,a,`"grid"`,b, col = "col1",sep="")%>%pull(col1)

[1] "paper1grid11" "paper1grid12" "paper1grid13" "paper2grid11" "paper2grid12" "paper2grid13"
[7] "paper3grid11" "paper3grid12" "paper3grid13"
```

Comment: you should include your library calls

Comment: I did this. You only need tidyverse.